# In coq, how to make proofs involving summations and means?

Tags: statistics, coq

For example, how to proof in coq that:

[image]

or that:

[image]

Comment: You should consider adding the definitions you're relying upon. One would for instance expect `mean(X)` to be *defined* by the first equation you suggest so the equality would be trivial.

Comment: But is the question really about proofs or rather about definitions, i.e. how to model these objects?

Comment: You could model Xi's as a list of nat (or whatever the type of X is) and the sum as a fold operator ?

Comment: Suspecting that the first problem could be at must and axiom or definition, I offered the second problem; I'm just starting with coq, so it is dificult to me to guess which is the simplest proof involving summations and means one can ask coq to prove. Thanks for the observations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many ways to state your lemmas and definitions, in particular it depends what your assumptions over the datatypes are. I recommend using the `bigop` library from the Mathematical Components Coq package. With it, you can prove your second lemma easily enough:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect all_algebra.

Section Avg.

Open Scope ring_scope.
Import GRing.Theory.

Variables (N : fieldType) (n : nat) (n_pos : n%:R != 0 :> N) (X : n.-tuple N).

Definition avg := (\sum_(x <- X) x) / n%:R.

Lemma avgP : \sum_(x <- X) (x - avg) = 0.
Proof.
rewrite sumrB !big_tuple sumr_const card_ord -mulr_natr divfK //.
by rewrite big_tuple subrr.
Qed.

End Avg.
```

Note that the above code is just meant as an example for you to get a feeling of a simple proof; properly developing a theory about statistic would require way more though and likely a different encoding of `avg`.

Comment: Since the OP is starting their Coq way, I think the [math-comp book](https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/) will make a great reading.

Comment: @ejgallego I'm waiting to have the proper time to check this answer.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Reading the Coq's tutorial, it is suggested to study the reference manual after the tutorial, would you advice to read the math-comp book first?

Comment: @LayGonzález That depends on you goals: if you want a large and mature *mathematical* library to back you up from the beginning, you should study the math-comp book. Keep, however, in mind that it is a different flavor of Coq. If you'd like vanilla Coq, then [SF](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html) would be a good start (1st part is about Coq and proving in general; 2nd part is about programming languages theory).

Comment: @AntonTrunov maybe I'll be able to decide my goals after completing the tutorial. Right now, I picked Coq out of the frustration of having to do the manual search for the proofs that I'm asked to do on my homeworks. But I'm curious about math in general. I hope to use coq to explore mathematical theories without needing a teacher. Actually, I do have as goal to selfstudy category theory with coq's aid ([relevant link](http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/Coq7_workshop/Coq7_submission_5.pdf))

Comment: I'd go straight to the math-comp book, then to the HoTT book, specially with your interests. However you will be frustate by how hard is doing proof in HoTT compared to mathcomp. By the way, doing category theory internally in Coq is _hard_

Comment: @ejgallego then why should I look at HoTT? Towards which goal would it lead me?

Comment: @LayGonzález math-comp includes lots of interesting mathematics, but no category theory. math-comp makes doing proofs very easy thanks to its tactics and libraries, HoTT has a less-developed support.

Comment: @ejgallego or is there another assistant better suited for learning category theory that you know of?

Comment: @LayGonzález that's a very good question, maybe you should open one! As far as I know Coq is pretty advanced, intensional type theory makes some constructions hard, however HoTT alleviates some issues, but a lot of technical baggage still appears. I don't know what is the status in Isabelle. RedPRL could be also an interesting proof, but I'm no familiar with it either.

Comment: Done http://stackoverflow.com/q/40857949/1120410 Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your time